# I am not able to connect to my oneplus buds z2 on my kde device

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth

I was able to connect till yesterday but I do not know what happened today.
I can pair the device but cannot connect to it.
It gives the following error message

```
Attempting to connect to E4:41:22:E2:9F:CB
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Here is the bluetoothctl output

```
[bluetooth]# info E4:41:22:E2:9F:CB
Device E4:41:22:E2:9F:CB (public)
        Name: OnePlus Buds Z2
        Alias: OnePlus Buds Z2
        Class: 0x00240404
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (00001107-d102-11e1-9b23-00025b00a5a5)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666)
        UUID: Vendor specific           (df21fe2c-2515-4fdb-8886-f12c4d67927c)
```

Comment: Providing software stack details (ie. OS & particularly release details) may help with clues.  Did you make any changes yesterday (esp. package changes)?

Comment: @guiverc Some packages updated at midnight but I couldn't find which packages due to them being updated via the kde gui app for updates. I think those updates broke my Bluetooth connection...

Comment: Did you look at what was updated in your `apt` logs?  (*assuming you're asking about deb packages*)  Upgrades appear in logs when initiated by terminal, unattended-upgrades or GUI program the same.

Comment: @guiverc I think these are the packages that were updated. But I do not know how they could break my bluetooth connections. brave-browser:amd64 , libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.10, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11), ssh-askpass-gnome:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5), docker-ce-rootless-extras:amd64 , openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.4, 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.5), firefox:amd64 , curl:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.10, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.10, 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11), docker-ce:amd64,docker-ce-cli:amd64 (5:20.10.15~3-0~ubuntu-focal,5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-focal)